# wpf ContextMenu IsEnabled and bindings

Tags: wpf

I have list of textboxes and context menu on each textbox. I need to gray out header of context menu item when command can not execute. But when I add IsEnabled binding:

```
<MenuItem Command="{Binding ConvertCommand}">
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <TextBlock IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}">
            <Run Text="{Binding Query, TargetNullValue=' — '}" />»
        </TextBlock>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

bindings inside TextBlock don't works *sometimes*, in some list's items (textboxes). How to fix that?

Comment: normally when the attached Command has `CanExecute()` returning `false`, the `MenuItem` should be grayed out automatically for you. Consider implementing your Command correctly. I mean somehow you have to raise `CanExecuteChanged` event.

Comment: Ok, I add IsEnabled trigger to TextBlock default style.